# Propriedade User, utilidade e possíveis casts

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net, asp.net-identity

Para fins didáticos, estava observando a propriedade ***User*** da classe *Controller* do *Asp.Net MVC*.

Vi um **[exemplo](http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-identity-stripped-bare-mvc-part-1)**, muito interessante, que uma classe base para os *controllers* foi implementada e ela possui a propriedade ***CurrentUser***:

```cs
public abstract class AppController : Controller
{
    public AppUserPrincipal CurrentUser {
        get { return new AppUserPrincipal(base.User as ClaimsPrincipal); }
    }
}
```

Essa propriedade ***User*** é aparentemente a mesma que existe no no *Asp.Net Webforms*, da qual nada sei também.
A propriedade ***User*** é do tipo ***IPrincipal*** e que implementa uma proprieade do tipo ***IIdentity*** e um método *`bool IsInRole(string role)`*.

Por sua vez, ***ClaimsPrincipal*** herda de *IPrincipal*, dando a entender porque o *cast* na propriedade ***CurrentUser*** é possível.
Mas a propriedade retorna mesmo é um tipo ***AppUserPrincipal*** que, apesar do nome, herda de *ClaimsPrincipal* e aplica algumas propriedades:

```cs
public class AppUserPrincipal : ClaimsPrincipal
{
    public AppUserPrincipal(ClaimsPrincipal principal): base(principal) { }

    public string Name {
        get { return this.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value; }
    }

    public string Country {
        get { return this.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Country).Value; }
    }
}
```

Bom, isso tudo até agora foi só para mostrar um pouco por onde andei e então facilitar a compreensão de minhas dúvidas.
Dúvidas essas porque ainda sou um total *newbie* no mundo de linguagens *Microsoft* e o ambiente **.Net**. Além claro de não ter entendido ainda a estrutura das classes e interfaces do *Asp.Net Identity* e como ele trabalha. Antes eu só programava para desktop com Delphi e muitas dúvidas eram resolvidas facilmente por poder acessar os fontes das classes, métodos e funções e ver como elas foram escritas.

Enfim, não sou de usar com constância e tranquilidade coisas que não entendeo. **Então as dúvidas são essas**:

1. O que é a propriedade ***User*** do *Controller* do *Asp.Net Mvc* e, é a mesma coisa que a de um *WebForm*? Qual a finalidade dela?
2. A propriedade ***User*** armazena as informações do usuário logado? Armazena em cookie ou em sessão?
3. Se eu herdar meu usuário de Identity consigo obter sua instância por meio de um cast? Ou não é necessário porque existiria uma outra forma?
4. A pergunta sobre a propriedade User armazenar uma instância do usuário vem, também, do método *`bool IsInRole(string role)`* da interface *IPrincipal*. Como sei que as roles que um usuário possui estarão ali? Como e onde isso é feito?

Fica nisso por enquanto para não deixarmos as respostas muito grande.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## O que é a propriedade User do Controller do Asp.Net Mvc e, é a mesma coisa que a de um WebForm? Qual a finalidade dela?

`User` é um objeto da interface [`IPrincipal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Security.Principal(v=vs.110).aspx). Um objeto `Principal` tem como finalidade identificar um usuário autenticado em uma aplicação ASP.NET. [A Microsoft escreveu um texto muito mais detalhado que pode ser lido aqui](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftx85f8x(v=vs.110).aspx).

## A propriedade User armazena as informações do usuário logado? Armazena em cookie ou em sessão?

Depende da implementação. [O nativo usa os dois](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/fx/src/xsp/System/Web/Security/RolePrincipal@cs/1305376/RolePrincipal@cs).

## Se eu herdar meu usuário de Identity consigo obter sua instância por meio de um cast? Ou não é necessário porque existiria uma outra forma?

Sim, consegue. Você só teria que implementar seu `CustomPrincipal`, implementando as interfaces requeridas por um objeto que herda de `IPrincipal`.

## A pergunta sobre a propriedade User armazenar uma instância do usuário vem, também, do método bool IsInRole(string role) da interface IPrincipal. Como sei que as roles que um usuário possui estarão ali? Como e onde isso é feito?

Isto é feito através do [`RoleManager`](https://www.symbolsource.org/MyGet/Metadata/aspnetwebstacknightly/Project/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/2.0.0-rtm-140226/Release/Default/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/RoleManager.cs), que é designado para responder à interface do `IPrincipal` quanto às Roles.